# Report Builder .rdl Check Array Key Exists

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I am making a report and I need to split a coma separated string into three columns of a table.

```
string = 'some text, some text, some text'
```

But the sting doesn't always have two coma's i.e.

```
string = 'some text, some text'
```

so when i try to get the value for the third column

```
=Split(Fields!GLDescription.Value, ", ").GetValue(2)
```

This code can result in a "#Error" message in the column. I tried to solve this by checking the length like so

```
=IIF(Split(Fields!GLDescription.Value, ", ").Length >= 3, Split(Fields!GLDescription.Value, ", ").GetValue(2), "")
```

But it still resulted in the same error. Is there anyway to check if an array key exists?

Answer (score 1):

The issue, as you've seen, is that SSRS `IIf` expressions aren't good at short circuiting. I can think of a workaround that will work for 2 and 3 column fields.

Try an expression like:

```
=IIf(
    Split(Fields!GLDescription.Value, ", ").Length = 3
    , Mid(
        Fields!GLDescription.Value
        , InStrRev(Fields!GLDescription.Value, ", ") + 2
        , Len(Fields!GLDescription.Value) - InStrRev(Fields!GLDescription.Value, ", ") + 2
    )
    , "No val 3"
)
```

With dataset:

[image]

Gives result:

[image]

It's not bulletproof for all possible situations, but might be enough for your data.